# C# Datagrid events fire when it is loaded (disable this)

Tags: c#, event-handling, startup

As mentioned above,

How can I disable (or some workaround programatically) this?

some pseudocode could be:

```
cellvaluechangedevent/rowaddedevent(sender,e){
     If(initial load of datagrid){
          //trap this, end of method
     }
     else{
          //do work
     }
}
```

Comment: You can create a local variable that is set to true when you are binding data and set it to false once you are done. Will that be enough?

Comment: Try to subscribe to event immediately after loading.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This was already my temporary solution. Buy I'm not the biggest fan of global variables :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to separate my data loading into its own method. As such, I can then detach handlers which may be fired during a load or refresh, and then simply re-attach when that process is finished. This also makes it easier (where applicable) to refresh the dgv data from other places in the code.

The key, in the context of your problem, is:

1. detach handler
2. fill `DataGridView` or attach data source, however you are doing that.
3. re-attach handler

```
private void LoadDataGrid()
{
    this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged -= new 
        DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);

    // Your code to load data here

    this.dataGridView1.CellValueChanged +=new 
        DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellValueChanged);
}

void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code to handle the cell value changing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you just want to bypass the first time it fired. 
Assume your `DataGridView` named `dataGridView1`, and assigned the original handler `dataGridView1_CellValueChanged`, then you can do:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {
    dataGridView1.CellValueChanged-=dataGridView1_CellValueChanged;

    dataGridView1.CellValueChanged+=
        (sender_, e_) => {
            MessageBox.Show("fired after first time");
        };
}
```

Comment: This would only work if my datagrid has only 1 column. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataGridView.IsCurrentCellDirty` or `IsCurrentRowDirty`

```
cellvaluechangedevent/rowaddedevent(sender,e){
 if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty) {
     If(initial load of datagrid){ 
          //trap this, end of method 
     }
     else{
          //do work
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: yes, i just copy and paste from your pseudocode then added `if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty) {}` :)